# No Careers invitations, and can't link SE accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, linked-accounts, jobs

I signed up for Careers yesterday (eligible because of my Github profile). I've filled out my profile to 170/210 completeness, but the invitations page still says

> Get to 150 completeness, and we’ll grant you a batch of invites.

And there's no indication that I have any invites yet.

[image]

Furthermore, even though Careers shows several of my Stack Overflow answers, it doesn't let me formally link my accounts:
[image]

Any ideas what's going on? Thanks in advance!

(P.S. my profile, though not yet public, is [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish/58171).)

Comment: My profile is 140/210 complete, and I have 5 invitations available; the difference is that I have got the invite from Careers to create a profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that jtbandes.  I've just fixed your issue and your Stack Exchange accounts should be there.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! Do you know what's going on with my invites?

Comment: (Also, out of curiosity, what was wrong?)

Comment: @jtbandes: We only grant invites Monday-Friday.  We had your network accounts in the database, but they were associated with an old identifier for your account so they weren't showing up on your profile page.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it's a manual process. Good to know — thanks again!

Comment: Following up, now that it's Monday, it seems I still don't have invitations. Should I expect this to take a couple days?

Comment: @jtbandes - You do now! :)

Comment: @JasonPunyon, I am also facing the same issue. I have a completion score of 152, at the time of this writing, and I don't see any invitation. Guess you are doing it manually for now !! It would be great if you can enable an invitation or two so that I can ask my hacker friends to come on the board, thanks !